# Applescript Tool:Copying files to preset directories based on team member names

Tags: applescript

I am not a programmer by trade, but an art director on a rather large project where I do many repetitive tasks on a daily basis. One constant is moving files to team member's folders. I want to be able to select some files and have a menu appear for me to choose who will receive the files.

I made some progress but am stuck. The script cannot find the directory I intend the files to go. I fear it has something to do with POSIX paths - or me not defining it as a folder rather than a file? The error reads:

**error "File /Volumes/Workbench/Test/CookieMonster wasn’t found." number -43 from "/Volumes/Workbench/Test/CookieMonster"**

...even thou there is a folder where it says there isn't. I suspect my syntax is incorrect somehow.

```
    set currentFolder to path to (folder of the front window) as alias
on error -- no open windows
    set the currentFolder to path to desktop folder as alias
end try
set artistList to {"CookieMonster", "BigBird", "Bert", "Ernie", "Grouch"}
set assignTo to {choose from list artistList with title "Assign to..." with prompt "Please choose" default items "Bert"}
set assignedArtist to result
set artDeptDir to "/Volumes/Workbench/Test/"
set filePath to {artDeptDir & assignedArtist}
set destinationFolder to filePath as alias
set selected_items to selection
repeat with x in selected_items
    move x to folder of filePath
end repeat
```

If anyone who has insight into my problem, I would love to hear from them. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the `Finder` doesn't accept POSIX paths. You have to use HFS paths (colon separated and starting with a disk name).

This version fixes another issue and redundant code was removed

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set currentFolder to (target of the front window) as alias
    on error -- no open windows
        set currentFolder to path to desktop
    end try
    set artistList to {"CookieMonster", "BigBird", "Bert", "Ernie", "Grouch"}
    -- no braces {} !
    set assignTo to (choose from list artistList with title "Assign to..." with prompt "Please choose" default items "Bert")
    if assignTo is false then return
    set assignedArtist to item 1 of assignTo
    -- no braces {} !
    set destinationFolder to "Workbench:Test:" & assignedArtist
    move selection to folder destinationFolder
end tell
```